# Check if value exists in the array (AngularJS)

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, object, angularjs-controller

Currently, I'm using the `forEach()`-method of angular to check the new value with the array of objects. But that's the wrong approach because, for example, in the list are 20 objects. When I'm creating an object with an existing article, then the if-statement in forEach tells one time the article is existing and 19 times it isn't.

The following code:

```
var list = [];

articlelist.forEach(function (val) {
   list.push(val.artNr);
});

$log.info(list);
```

The `articlelist`contains all 20 objects. For comparing, I only need the `artNr`. Because when the User creates a new article, then should be an if-Statement to check if the added artNr is already existing.

```
$scope.createItem = function (createItem) {
  if(list.artNr === createItem.artNr) {
      $scope.message = 'artNr already exists!';
  }
...
};
```

The problem is, that list.artNr returns me "undefined" because the list variable is an array:

> list output in console => `Array ["AB001", "AB002", "AB003", "AB004"]`,
>
> createItem output: => `Object { artNr: "AB001", description: "New Article" ...}`

How can I compare the new created object with the array from the list variable?

Comment: `indexOf` method didn't work for me as I was using json object array retrieved from the local storage. After trying many different methods, I have decided to use $filter provider available in AngularJS.

`var articlelist = [ {id: 1, title: 'Title1'}, {id: 2, title: 'Title2'}, {id: 3, title: 'Title3'} ]`
`var o = $filter('filter')(articlelist, { 'id': new_title.id }, true);`
`                if (o.length == 0) {`
`                    articlelist .push(new_article);`
`                }`

Answer (score 145, accepted):

You could use `indexOf` function.

```
if(list.indexOf(createItem.artNr) !== -1) {
  $scope.message = 'artNr already exists!';
}
```

More about indexOf:

- http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof_array.asp
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf

Comment: Thanks.. I've forgotten the indexOf() method!

Comment: again simple and clean function that is available in almost all browsers. It is only not supported on very old versions of [Firefox and IE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf#Browser_compatibility).

Comment: I too forgot about this function, awesome simple answer right here.

Answer (score 32):

You can use **indexOf()**. Like:

```
var Color = ["blue", "black", "brown", "gold"];
var a = Color.indexOf("brown");
alert(a);
```

The ***indexOf()*** method searches the array for the specified item, and returns its position. And return **-1** if the item is not found.

---

If you want to search from end to start, use the **lastIndexOf()** method:

```
    var Color = ["blue", "black", "brown", "gold"];
    var a = Color.lastIndexOf("brown");
    alert(a);
```

The search will start at the specified position, or at the end if no start position is specified, and end the search at the beginning of the array.

Returns **-1** if the item is not found.

Comment: Thanks for this clear share Muhammed.

Answer (score 1):

U can use something like this....

```
  function (field,value) {

         var newItemOrder= value;
          // Make sure user hasnt already added this item
        angular.forEach(arr, function(item) {
            if (newItemOrder == item.value) {
                arr.splice(arr.pop(item));

            } });

        submitFields.push({"field":field,"value":value});
    };
```

Comment: this is a terrible way to do it... Think about a small list of 100 records which includes duplicate records.. For each record, you are going to loop through the added records